# flip image horizontal in c

Tags: c, image, swap

My function is getting an Image and I am trying to show the mirror of it.
horizonal flip. I tried to do something like swap function, but it prints the original picture.

The size of the image is m*n and the function knows the values of m and n.

Here is my code:

```
void flipfunc(Img *img)
{
    int y;
    int x;
    const int middleX = m / 2;
    char tmp;
    char* p;

    for (x = 0; x < middleX; ++x)
    {
        p = image->data + x * m;
        for (y = 0; y <3*n; y+=3)
        {
            // swap pixels
            tmp = p[y];
            p[y] = p[3*n - 1 - y];
            p[3*n - 1 - y] = tmp;
            tmp = p[y+1];
            p[y+1] = p[3*n - 1 - (y+1)];
            p[3*n - 1 - y] = tmp;
            tmp = p[y+2];
            p[y+2] = p[3*n - 1 - (y+2)];
            p[3*n - 1 - (y+2)] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

/* Image type - contains height, width, and RGB data */

```
struct Img {
    unsigned long X;
    unsigned long Y;
    char *data;
};
```

Comment: btw the code should use optimizations. but i hope it will work first.

Comment: What is `m`???? Where is it declared? Any good reason why `m` and `n` which should be called `width` and `height` are not members of the `Image` structure?

Comment: the function knows its value. i dont know why. it compiles.

Comment: its part of other files we should just make this function and assume the function knows the values of m and n when i fun the function it really works but doesnt doing the expected

Comment: That's not enough, really bad design choice!!! The value might be altered everywhere in the program, don't you think that is dangerous? You must add `width` and `height` to the `Image` structure and populate them when you load the image.

Comment: What is `Image` defined to be and what exactly does it represent? Specifically, what is the `data` format? Please provide *complete and clear* information. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a description of the expected information in a question.

Comment: And also, an input image and what the output is!

Comment: /* Image type - contains height, width, and RGB data */
struct Image {
 unsigned long sizeX;
 unsigned long sizeY;
 char *data;
};
for example

n = image->sizeX; // width
 m = image->sizeY; // height

Comment: different behavior, I think, if m is odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the issues that other mentioned in the comments, I'll try to answer with a few hints:

1) In your function, you want to do an in-place mirroring of the given rgb image. That's reasonable.

2) You were thinking in the right direction with your "middleX" and your pixel-swapping approach. BUT it seems you did it wrong: You ignore the top half of your image completely, and instead swap each row of the bottom half twice! That's why you end up with the same image in the end. So why don't you just apply your "middle" logic to the inner loop instead of the outer loop?

Answer (score 0):

Images are usually stored in a row-major raster order. That is, all pixels of the first row come before (=their addresses are smaller than) pixels of the second row, the third row, etc.

To visualize an example image of width 5 and height 4:

```
RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB
RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB
RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB
RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB
```

Each letter represents a byte in memory; spaces are just for clarity.

To find a specific sample in the image, you must do some arithmetic. For example, locate a `G` sample of pixel with x=1 and y=2. I marked it with a capital G:

```
,,, ,,, ,,, ,,, ,,,
,,, ,,, ,,, ,,, ,,,
,,, ,G. ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

To find its offset in the `data` array, count the number of samples that come before it (I marked them with `,`). If you fiddle with it enough, you can discover this formula:

```
offset = y * 3 * sizeX + x * 3 + k;
```

where `k` is `0`, `1`, or `2`, depending on which colour you are looking for.

Your code has (for example)

```
x * m + y
```

which is not correct at all.

BTW you shouldn't use variable names like `m` or `n` - they are extremely confusing. Just use

```
image->sizeX
```

or, if you want to use temporary variables:

```
unsigned long sizeX = image->sizeX;
```

Comment: did not understand. how should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should be working:

```
void flipfunc(Img *img)
{
    int y;
    int x;
    int l, r;
    char tmp;

    for (y = 0; y < img->y; ++ y) {
        for (l = 0, r = img->x - 1; l < r; ++ l, -- r) {
            for (d = 0; d < 3; ++ d) {
                tmp = img->data[(y * img->x + l) * 3 + d];
                img->data[(y * img->x + l) * 3 + d] = img->data[(y * img->x + r) * 3 + d];
                img->data[(y * img->x + r) * 3 + d] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want something, let's say, more optimized, build it with -O2.